# How to schedule a command to run a few seconds after startup?

Tags: mount, virtualization, cron

I was trying to use `@reboot /my/script` in `cron` to run a script on a `10.04.4` VM running in `VMware Fusion` top print `ifconfig` to a file on a shared directory, which is `/mnt/hgfs/somedir`.

It didn't work because `hgfs` is not mounted yet as a remote directory when the system starts.  Is it possible to do something like `@reboot +10s` to run the cron job 10 sec after the system starts, when I can realistically expect to have that remote directory mounted on the system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply add

```
sleep 10
```

to the beginning of your script. This way, your script will "sleep" (wait) 10 seconds before continuing.

Comment: brilliant, thanks.  why didn't i think of that?

Answer (score 2):

For a more robust option, your cron job could be

```
 @reboot until [ -d /mnt/hgfs/somedir ]; do sleep 1; done; /my/script
```

That will wait until the directory actually exists, so you don't need to guess how long it will take or worry that it might take longer.